# Setup an imageview to open sidebar/menu android

Tags: android, menu, imageview, sidebar

Instead of using actionbar and setting up an icon, I could not use actionbar here. What I really want to do is to setup an imageview, which responds to user's click. When it is clicked, sidebar/menu will open or close, just like clicking on physical button at the button of android phone.
Is there any easy way to do so? (all the items in the sidebar are already done and work fine. I checked it by clicking on physical menu button on my phone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Felt worthwhile to put the code for this example up on [GitHub](https://github.com/PPartisan/TestNavButtonMenu), as it was getting quite long:**

Just set an `OnClickListener` to your `ImageView`, in the same way you would a `Button`.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
//...
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(!mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } 
}
```

You may want to add `android:clickable = "true"` to the `xml` for your `ImageView`, and `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` to gain feedback when the item is clicked.

This assumes you've set up your DrawerLayout somewhat like the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = null;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle = null;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView = null;
    private NavMenuAdapter adapter = null;

    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, 0, 0);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_menu_recycler);

        adapter = new NavMenuAdapter();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

**Edit:**
If you would like more control, you can define various states for your `ImageView` with a [state list drawable](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList), and use it in `android:background` instead of the above suggestion. Create a new `xml` file in your `drawable` folder (i.e. `custom_selector.xml`) with the following template:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_focused"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_normal" />
</selector>
```

And define relevant images for pressed, focused/hover and normal states. Apply it  with:

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_selector"
```

Comment: What exactly should I implement I onClick function? As I was trying to modify a code, which originally uses action bar, I need to modify it without using action bar at all. How could I connect imageview and the menu object? Thanks man!

Comment: @Yao Ah, I see. Take a look at my edit for one possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Building on PPartisan's answer, and assuming your Activity is MainActivity:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
//...
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   MainActivity.this.openOptionsMenu();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.