# Side Menu with ImageButton

Tags: android

I have the following implementation side menu implementation. In that implementation, it requires to have `ActionBar`.

But I want to disable `ActionBar` and add an `ImageButton` instead, which allows user opens or closes the side menu. How could I do that?

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle (this, mDrawerLayout, Resource.Drawable.icon, Resource.String.open_drawer, Resource.String.close_drawer);

protected override void OnPostCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnPostCreate (savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.SyncState ();
}

public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected (IMenuItem item)
{
    if (mDrawerToggle.OnOptionsItemSelected (item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected (item);
}
```

Comment: Are you willing to use toolbar ?

Comment: [I answered an exact question yesterday, with an example app on GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922597/setup-an-imageview-to-open-sidebar-menu-android/31923113#31923113)

Comment: no, I want to use `ImageButton` which triggers open and close side menu (side drawer).

Comment: @AndreaBanderas It's practically identical, just replace `ImageView` for `ImageButton`

Comment: You could use an ImageButton to trigger it with toolbar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
mDrawerButton = FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.sidemenubutton);

mDrawerButton.Click += delegate {
    if(!mDrawerLayout.IsDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.Start)) {
        mDrawerLayout.OpenDrawer(GravityCompat.Start);
    } else {
        mDrawerLayout.CloseDrawer(GravityCompat.Start);
    } 
};
```